# Best use of vertical lines separating words in logo

Tags: logo, typography, composition

What are some of the pros and cons of enlarging the vertical lines between words in a logo like this? One I can think of, it makes the logo boundaries larger. Is it best to stick with vertical lines of the same thickness as the type or a different size?

[image: Brackets matching character size in wording]

[image: Brackets Larger than characters in wording]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to vote to close this as "Opinion-based". I can't see how this can be answered objectively. My personal *opinion* about this particular case is to go with the long lines. The short ones look too much like I's. But they don't have to be *that* long and you can also adjust the spacing.

Comment: AFAIK, brackets are these characters: []. That character (or other similar characters) is an upright slash or vertical bar. It's also worth noting that dividers like those are often *not* part of the type and are instead added as separate elements. Doing so gives more flexibility.

Comment: I stand corrected - Vertical Bar is the way I'll refer to these characters and "wording" as "Type". As you may have deduced, my question is characteristic of an amateur. Just asking those extensively versed in this area for your opinions and guidance.

Comment: Yeah, I'd call it a separator or vertical line.  Many fonts have a specific glyph for this. 0x7C or U+007C.  The top example looks like a letter "I" and is too short in my opinion. The size will probably depend on the font thowever.  If there's no suitable glyph, you could just draw a line.

Comment: I'm the end user of this Logo. I don't have a subscription to AI or the knowledge to alter the Logo. I have zero exposure to Graphics Design. Do I need to download the subscription of Adobe AI to be able to edit or alter/resize the Logo? Additionally, what is a good program to view EPS files? I guess Adobe sticks me with monthly subscription just to be able to view the size, DPI & pixels?

Comment: @James Inkscape for vector, Gimp for pixel (best known free software not necessary best ones out there). Affinity for affordable versions of Adobe products. There surly are posts here with in-dept suggestions & comparisons of design editors.

Comment: And as end user of a logo it is in general a very terrible idea to edit the logo  yourself. Have it done by a professional designer (or at least a cheap amateur designer from fiverr if there is no budget).

Comment: Personally I would abandon the vertical bar and consider a different separator - maybe the humble bullet: ANALYSIS • SYSTEMS • TOOLS

Comment: I agree with @Wolff in that this is entirely opinion-based. In addition, without seeing the *entire mark* everyone is just guessing at what may or may not be appropriate. The only sure thing is, if you are using vertical bars, they should be taller or shorter than the actual type, never the same height. And they should be thinner than the strokes on the type.

Answer (score 6):

The first one I would consider bad practice as it can be read as capital "i", which negatively impacts the readability.

[image]

---

Second one isn't good either, the divider is bolder than the word indicating it is the more important element.

[image]

---

Third one is ok(-ish)

[image]

---

Better options could include a lighter weight, grey colour, with whitespace or written as list. – Which of those is best is subjective and depends on context of the branding.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Julian Steinmann, Great review! The dark thin Vertical Bar looks good. I may ask them to reduce the length of the Vertical Bar to half the distance they are now from the surrounding Type to see how that looks and get a look at the same the thickness your example is showing above in your second version. Thank you all for helping an armature in the field of Graphic Design understand a portion of it.

Comment: Would look crammed. Whitespace allows text to breath. =)

Comment: +1 Yes `:)` Always taller or shorter and always thinner. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are no specific rules, so this is based on personal preference, but I would definitely go with lines higher than the wording, and possibly in thinner line to compensate for the size difference.